# os.system() and subprocess.Popen() kill escape sequences in Python

Tags: python, tmux

I use libtmux and libtmux uses subprocess.Popen() to invoke Tmux to control session, windows and panes. To set a pane titel Tmux requires to send an escape sequens. This works on command line as expected:

```
tmux send-keys -t 0 " printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'Pane Title'" C-m
```

When this command is issued by subprocess.Popen() or os.system() - may be others too, I've only tested these two - the escape squence does not make it to the shell. I logg the command sent to a file and the values in the log file are correct but when sent only this survives:

```
printf '2;%s' 'Pane Title'
```

I've tested this by executing this command:

```
echo "printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'Pane Title'" > /tmp/setname
```

The content of /tmp/setname is the above.

The methode finally used is [tmux_cmd](https://github.com/tmux-python/libtmux/blob/v0.23.2/src/libtmux/common.py#L196) and I call it via [send_keys](https://github.com/tmux-python/libtmux/blob/v0.23.2/src/libtmux/pane.py#L196) like this:

```
 p.send_keys("printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' '" + names[i] + "'")
```

where "p" is the pane object. See my post [here](https://github.com/tony/libtmux/issues/29).

My question is: How to issue shell commands with escape sequences in Python?

Comment: can you show us your python code?

Comment: You have a typo in your escape sequences: `]` instead of `[`. FWIW, I have no problems sending escape sequences to the KDE konsole terminal with either `os.system` or `subprocess`. Here's my test code. `import os, subprocess` `cmd = 'echo "this is \033[32mcoloured\033[0m text"'; os.system(cmd); subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`. Tested on Python 2.6 and 3.6.

Comment: @PM2Ring I wanted to see the code just to see if OP did use raw prefixes (which musn't be used in that case)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure, there _may_ be other problems with the OP's code. So I agree with your comment, which is why I upvoted it. ;)

Comment: the escape sequence is correct - it works on commandline, see:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/680

the method used finally is tmux_cmd:
https://github.com/tony/libtmux/blob/master/libtmux/common.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"raw prefixes" was what I've missed! Thanks [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre)!

This works:

```
p.send_keys(r"printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' '" + names[i] + "'")
```